# AS3935 lightning sensor

Tags: sensor

.  I am trying to get an AS3935 i2c sensor working on Raspberry Pi Zero.  I am using code I downloaded from web.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
_AS3935 import RPi_AS3935

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from datetime import datetime

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Rev. 1 Raspberry Pis should leave bus set at 0, while rev. 2 Pis should set
# bus equal to 1. The address should be changed to match the address of the
# sensor. (Common implementations are in README.md)
sensor = RPi_AS3935(address=0x03, bus=1)
```

I am getting error message:

```
sensor = RPi_AS3935(address=0x03, bus=1)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          03 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- 76 --
```

I've got the address and bus set correctly according to this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: your code example does not look complete and is definitely not formatted correctly.

Comment: This is my first attempt at posting on this site.  I had the info formatted correctly in the comment area, but it showed up completely different on the 'draft' section.  Live and learn!

Comment: You'd learn more about the formatting if you clicked on the `?` in the URHC of the composition window. FYI, a "flavor" of [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) is used here.

Comment: 0x03 is an unusual I2C address, possibly illegal as far as Linux drivers are concerned.  Can you change it to another address (perhaps in the range 0x10 to 0x6F)?

Comment: You have observed to the person who wasted their time writing an answer based on a typo/copy-paste malfunction/interface confusion/whatever problem that the code in the question is wrong, not what you are really using, whoops, sorry.  *IF YOU KNOW THE INFORMATION IN YOUR QUESTION IS INCORRECT, BE CONSIDERATE AND EDIT THE QUESTION TO CORRECT THAT INFORMATION* so that more people do not waste time analyzing the wrong problem.  If you do this the question can be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

this part of your code looks weird (line 2):

```
_AS3935 import RPi_AS3935
```

I believe you should call it this way:

```
from library import what_you_need
```

or:

```
import what_you_need
```

in this case what_you_need is RPi_AS3935
so I would assume you need:

```
import RPi_AS3935
```

only then you can call it - actually the error message gave you this hint

if you go to the library github you will find the good example:
[github-demo](https://github.com/pcfens/RaspberryPi-AS3935/blob/master/demo.py)

Comment: When I entered the code into the stackexchange window it changed it for some reason.  That line of code should have been "from RPi_AS3935 import RPi_AS3925".  I think this is a problem in the code, not in the hardware.  I have seen other people attaching the same sensor and getting the 0x03 and bus 1 readings on their i2c sensor

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  The code at github is what I am using as my base.  I've installed the RPi_AS3935 library, and as per the github demo, changed the sensor address to match my hardware, 0x03 and bus 1.  This seems to be happening well before any hardware is addresses.  I can't figure out why it won't call the module